# Node inspector not showing source files

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, node-inspector

Since last week (March 25th), I am unable debug using node inspect. I have been using node 8.11.4, and have not updated node version.

After I run `node --inspect filename.js` I was able to go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` and click on **Open dedicated DevTools for Node**, and this used to attach the debugger and load the file.

Now it doesn't show anything in the inspect window.

However, it does show file in `Remote Target`, but only those files are shown that I had opened previously. I still don't see any files in Sidebar. And `Reveal in Sidebar` does not show me the current file.

I am using Chrome `Version 73.0.3683.86`.

[image: Chrome node inspect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in chrome:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=941608#c15

The fix is due for release in the next version (22nd April).  In the meantime, either use NiM (chrome extension) or download the google chrome beta.  I can confirm that it is working again using chrome beta.

https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/

Comment: Gaawd.. Thanks. I was losing my mind. I re-installed every possible tool I was using.